# How to change JButton property?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I want to change button text when i click on it, but it does not appears on the GUI. In intellje IDE i can see it is changed but why does not appear in GUI?
This is code snip:

```
final WebLabel loading = new WebLabel("Disconnected...",  IconLib.ICON_19X17_THICK_ARROW_RIGHT_LIGHTBLUE.getIcon(), SwingConstants.CENTER);
final WebLabel ipLabel = new WebLabel(host);
final JPanel horizontalMiddlePanel = new JPanel();
final WebButton disconnect = new WebButton("Connect",    IconLib.ICON_16X16_QUESTIONMARK_ON_BLUE_CIRCLE.getIcon());
    disconnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (loading.getText().equals("Connected...")) {
                loading.setText("Disconnected...");
                loading.setIcon(IconLib.ICON_19X17_THICK_ARROW_RIGHT_LIGHTBLUE.getIcon());
                disconnect.setText("Connect");

            } else {
                loading.setText("test");
                loading.setIcon(IconLib.ICON_19X17_THICK_ARROW_RIGHT.getIcon());
                ipLabel.setText(ipLabel.getText().replace(" Unreachable try again",""));
                ipLabel.setForeground(Color.green);
                disconnect.setText("Connecting");
                callflexConnection(ipLabel, 3001, loading, disconnect);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is WebLabel and WebButton?

Answer (score 2):

than not possible without spliting code to to the two parts

1) update `JButton#setText`

then

2) executing rest of code

- by delaing by using `javax.swing.Timer`
- execute from `SwingWorker`
- wrap inside `Runnble#Thread`,

3) this code is executed on EDT, then all changes are done on EDT, end in same/one moment

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell if it's the source of your current problem or not, but performing logic in code based on the current text on a button is a flimsy way to do things. You should maintain that connection state in a dedicated variable. Something like this:

```
private enum ConnState {
    CONN_DISCONNECTED,
    CONN_CONNECTING,
    CONN_CONNECTED,
};

private ConnState connState;

private void setConnState(ConnState connState) {
    this.connState = connState;
    switch (connState) {
    case CONN_DISCONNECTED:
        loading.setText("Disconnected");
        disconnect.setText("Connect");
        break;
    case CONN_CONNECTING:
        loading.setText(...etc...);
        disconnect.setText(...);
        break;
    case CONN_CONNECTED:
        loading.setText(...);
        disconnect.setText(...);
        break;
    }
}
```

And call this when setting up the GUI to initialize the button text and `connState`:

```
setConnState(CONN_DISCONNECTED);
```

Then you can reason robustly about the current state of the program by checking the `connState` variable instead of having to synchronize button strings everywhere.

Comment: you seem to know what `WebLabel` and `WebButton` are, maybe you could retag or add tag to the question?

Comment: @Oleg: They appear to be extensions of JButton, but I don't know.